# JWT Local storage , Cookies and Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jwt, local-storage

I understand the difference between cookie based and JWT based authentication.

I understand that before calling API via fetch, I can access local storage to get token value and pass it via request.
How will this work if I reload the page? If I had used cookies, it would automatically be sent in the HTTP request.

Please help to get it clarified.

Comment: Data in localstorage won't get removed when you reload page.

Comment: Correct.
I am thinking How will browser pass JWT string to server If I reload the page.
If it was an ajax call , i could have accessed localstorage and passed it along the request.

Comment: The browser doesn't do anything with localstorage by itself, so it won't include the JWT string.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling:
Are you suggesting like for multi page application with authorization and authentication enabled, we can't go by JWT stored in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should send a http-only cookie to your client. The cookie could contain a jwt token. Then, simply attach this cookie to all your requests.

If you're using axios you can do it with `withCredentials: true`. If you're using a vanilla XHR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials for more information.

So when the user opens the page, calls the server, and knows whether he's logged-in or not. If so, just add a `isLogged: true` in sessionStorage.

This would be a simple and secure solution.

Comment: Hi @DoneDeal0
So can I confirm that using JWT with localstorage is not suitable for a multi page application?

Comment: You can. It's just not secure at all. Anyone and any script can access and decode it. If you want your token to be secure, use http-only cookie.

Comment: I still can't figure out how storing JWT in localstorage works with multipage application.
Supplose I have Page A, Page B, Page C in my application.
From Page A, I do login and get redirected to Page B.
From Page B , If I do a page refresh, how will back end server know that I am a logged in user (since JWT is stored in localstorage and do not automatically get passed in browser GET request for Page B)?

Comment: If you have a jwt stored in local storage, you can check it in your frontend, and know that the user is logged-in. You can then prevent api call according to this information. But the "right" way to do it is to pass a cookie to all your api request, so the backend can parse it and check its validity (does it come from the right domain, is it still valid, etc.), before allowing access to a route.